# Apache + PHP-FPM + Global x Custom 404

Tags: php-fpm, apache2

I have server with many virtual hosts. Now I want migrate to PHP-FPM (from mod_php).

Now I have `ErrorDocument 404  /error-httpd/404.php` in Apache server config. But problem is with PHP-FPM, because when file is not exist proxy return "File not found" only and no custom 404.

One solution what is not for me is ProxyErrorOverride On - but this suppresses 404 responses generate directly in PHP script.

Another solution what is not for me is this in every VH:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+\.php$ /error-httpd/404.php
```

For standard domains it is ok, but not for virtual subdomains generate with:

```
RewriteCond /www/sub.domain.net/%3.sub.domain.net -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/sub.domain.net/%2/$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

After this every scripts in subdomains (without index.php) is 404.

So I don't know what I can try more. Thank you for tisp.

EDIT 1

Proxy conf lines from virtual hosts:

```
<FilesMatch \".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$\">
SetHandler \"proxy:unix:/var/run/domain.net.sock|fcgi://localhost/\"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Could you post all information from the log regarding _"File not found"_, which file and its path was not found? Maybe you have problem with proxy, virtual host might refer to relative location e.g `http://virtual_host_ip.domain/error-http/404.php`, cold you post relevant proxy configuration? Instead of relative path to 404.php try with absolute.

Comment: /error-httpd/ it is alias directory and served via another php-fpm socket than virtual host. when I call no-php not-exist file it is fine.

Comment: @dexter - proxy config in edit1

Comment: @dexter and sorry for little spam - but problem is with second solution that files are in subdomains, but PHP return not found.

Comment: Alternatives to `ProxyErrorOverride`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72320136/2032498